# Connect to long running socket API

Tags: c#, api, sockets, tcp, connection

my application has a requirment to connect to a keep-alive API socket. Which means:

1. I connect to API once
2. The API returns the initial set of data
3. When action is posted to API from other client, the API returns new data to my client

The problem is: **I don't know how to connect to the API from my C# application**.

I've tried using:

- Socket
- Socket.io
- WebSocket
- WebSocketSharp
- TcpClient
- HttpClient

But to no avail. In cases of **WebSocket** I get an error saying that "this is not a websocket handshake". In case of **TcpClient** the host is unknown. In case of **HttpClient** I just don't get any response from the API.

The API documentation here might be helpful to identify my problem.
http://developer.geniussports.com/warehouse/old/guide/guide_livestream_read.html

Comment: how about auth - doc mentioned `Each API call must include the query string parameter ak` ? .  Try to connect to at least pure REST methods - than go for web-sockets

Comment: I'm using the API key. When I put the API link into my browser I get the live feed which I need.

Comment: then try to sniff the traffic via http analizer for example and try to see the difference between your request and request from the browser

Comment: Am I looking in the right place and what am I supposed to see?
https://ibb.co/FHmx5tq

Comment: yes, you`ve got an URL of the GET request - in response will see what goes with the results. Try to emulate same request from C# usualy TCP Socket

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "your long polling API request URL";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(
        request, 
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        using (var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(body))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

This worked.